# Solver Looping Issues in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, excel, for-loop

I am having difficulty with solver. I have tried to develop a for-loop that would call solver many times but I am having issues. I have already added the reference of solver to the workbook from tools/references. I have successfully gotten the loop to work with the solver; unfortunately, solver won't change my input cells automatically. I felt that this issue could be resolved by the SolverReset function but every time I use it it fails, and the loop can no longer find a solution without manually re-solving the system. My code is as follows.

```
 Sub Go_Click() 

    'Variable Types
    Dim x As Double 
    Dim First_Variable As Range 
    Dim Second_Variable As Range 
    Dim Number_of_Calculations As Double 
    Dim Input_Cells As Range 
    Dim First_Dimension_Lower As Double 
    Dim y As Double 

    Number_of_Calculations = 6 

    x = (First_Dimension_Upper_Bound - First_Dimension_Lower_Bound) /  Number_of_Calculations 

    For y = 1 To Number_of_Calculations 

         ' x is the integer that the first dimension of the solve will increase by.
         ' by finding the difference between the upper and lower bound and dividing by the number of calculations
         ' then the rest is just a for loop, adding the value "x" to each loop

        SolverOk SetCell:="First_Dimension", _ 
        MaxMinVal:=3, _ 
        ValueOf:=First_Dimension_Lower_Bound, _ 
        ByChange:="Input_Cells", _ 
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear" 
        SolverSolve 

         'Just to test the results
         MsgBox (Range("b4")) 

         'increase in the lower first dimension bound
         First_Dimension_Lower_Bound = First_Dimension_Lower_Bound + x 

     Next y 

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the return result of [SolverSolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197237.aspx) to discover if it completed successfully:

> If a Solver problem has not been completely defined, SolverSolve
>   returns the #N/A error value. Otherwise the Solver runs, and
>   SolverSolve returns an integer value corresponding to the message that
>   appears in the Solver Results dialog box.

The linked page lists the possible integer values that are returned. For example, 5 indicates "Solver could not find a feasible solution".

You can also supply a Function name as the `ShowRef` argument to `SolverSolve`:

```
SolverSolve(UserFinish, ShowRef)
```

This Function will be called if Solver pauses for one of the reasons listed in the linked page. For example, 2 means:

> Function called because the Max Time limit in the Solver Options
>   dialog box was exceeded.

Comment: Ok, so I tried the ShowRef Function in SolverSolve and I absolutely got nothing, Meaning my variable cells didn't even change. I also removed the UserFinish=true to see what the solver dialog box would say. It said that the solver found a solution for an incorrect Objective cell (the data that was already in solver- inputted manually). The best way that I can sum this problem up is: My code won't talk to the solver. Here is my code (I started ignoring the loop for now to focus on this problem first)

Comment: VB:
        SolverOk SetCell:="First_Dimension", _
        MaxMinVal:=3, _
        ValueOf:=First_Dimension_Lower_Bound, _
        ByChange:="Input_Cells", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True, ShowRef:="A20"

(Sorry I couldn't the code formatting to work)

Comment: It looks you need to change the values of your parameters. The SetCell:="First_Dimension" is not using the named range but just a string "First_Dimension". So there is no reference to a range. If you are using the named range then try SetCell:=Range("First_Dimension"). Same for "Input_Cells".